# LXML: remove the x

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am creating a sitemap parser with LXML and want to extract the tags with its' values.
The resulted tags, however, always contain the xmlns information e.g. `{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc`.

```
body = cStringIO.StringIO(item['body'])
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True, load_dtd=True, ns_clean=True)
tree = etree.parse(body, parser)

for sitemap in tree.xpath('./*'):
    print sitemap.xpath('./*')[0].tag
    # prints: {http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc
```

The sitemap string:

```
<sitemap xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <loc>http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml</loc>
  <lastmod>2011-12-22T15:46:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
```

I want to extract only the tag - here 'loc', without `{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}`. Is there a way in LXML to configure the parser
or LXML in that way?

**Note**: I know that I can use a simple regex replacement - a friend told me to ask for 
help if an implementation feels more complicated than it should be.

Comment: I can't see a way to do this. This thread on the LXML mailing list https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/2012-June/006454.html is about the same question, and has a few ideas. However, it does seem there is nothing as simple as being able to say `element.localname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a perfect world you would use an XML parsing or html scraping library to parse your html to make sure you have the exact tags that you need, in context.  It is almost certainly simpler, quicker and good enough in this case to simply use a regular expression to match what you need.

```
>>> import re
>>> samp = """<sitemap xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...     <loc>http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml</loc>
...     <lastmod>2011-12-22T15:46:17+00:00</lastmod>
... </sitemap>"""
>>> re.findall(r'<loc>(.*)</loc>', samp)
['http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml']
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best approach, but it uses `lxml` as you've asked and it works:

```
import cStringIO
from lxml import etree


text = """<sitemap xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <loc>http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2011-12-22T15:46:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>"""

body = cStringIO.StringIO(text)
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True, load_dtd=True, ns_clean=True)
tree = etree.parse(body, parser)

for item in tree.xpath("./*"):
    if 'loc' in item.tag:
        print item.text
```

prints

```
http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this with this tool.

htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

a friend told me it was simple and indeed !! much better than beautifulsoup or anything like.

```
from ehp import *

data = '''
<sitemap xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <loc>http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml</loc>
  <lastmod>2011-12-22T15:46:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>'''

html = Html()
dom  = html.feed(data)
seq  = [ind.text() for ind in dom.find('loc')]

print seq

# It gives me.
# ['http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml']
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you meant removing the  tag and leaving the text.
so it goes another answer.

```
from ehp import *

data = '''
<sitemap xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <loc>http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml</loc>
  <lastmod>2011-12-22T15:46:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>'''

html = Html()
dom  = html.feed(data)

for root, ind in dom.find_with_root('loc'):
    root.remove(ind)
    root.append(Data(ind.text()))


# It would give me.
print dom



""" <sitemap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" >

  <lastmod >2011-12-22T15:46:17+00:00</lastmod>
http://www.some_page.com/sitemap-page-2010-11.xml</sitemap>
"""
```